# ping site if offline run another vbs

Tags: vbscript, ping

I am looking for a way to ping a hostname via a VBScript and if it fails after some bad counts, if offline, it runs another vbs file.

I have many scripts that can ping a host via VBScript, but I don't know and I couldn't find a way to ping a host and if not pinging, to redirect and run another VBScript.

I've tried to add in the end of one of those scripts something like:

If strFailedPings = "" Then
        WScript.Echo "Ping status of specified computers is OK"
    Else

(here is the place that goes the code to open another vbs)

Example:

```
strComputers = "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.4"
arrComputers = Split(strComputers, ",")

For Each strComputer In arrComputers
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}")._
        ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_PingStatus WHERE address = '" & _
        strComputer & "'")
    For Each objPingStatus In objPing
        If IsNull(objPingStatus.StatusCode) Or objPingStatus.StatusCode<>0 Then
            If strFailedPings <> "" Then strFailedPings = strFailedPings & vbCrLf
            strFailedPings = strFailedPings & strComputer
        End If
    Next
Next

If strFailedPings = "" Then
    WScript.Echo "Ping status of specified computers is OK"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Ping failed for the following computers:" & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strFailedPings
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the WMI query n times in a `For` loop and count and count the failed pings, then run the other script if the fail count exceeds a given threshold.

```vb
n = 3
threshold = 1

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

For Each strComputer In arrComputers
    qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE address='" & strComputer & "'"
    cnt = 0
    For i = 1 To n
        For Each objPingStatus In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
            If IsNull(objPingStatus.StatusCode) Or objPingStatus.StatusCode<>0 Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If cnt > threshold Then
        'ping failed 2 or more times
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "wscript.exe ""C:\other\script.vbs""", 0, True
    End If
Next
```

Side note: you may want to distinguish between `sNull(objPingStatus.StatusCode)` and `objPingStatus.StatusCode<>0`. Only the latter represents the actual ping status. The former indicates a WMI error.

Comment: Where do I put the IP address or the machine name?

Comment: @Malbordio What do you mean "where"? Populate `arrComputers` the same way you did before.

Comment: I c...

Populate this:

`strComputers = "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.4"
arrComputers = Split(strComputers, ",")`


before the script

Comment: I'm having the following error while running the script:

Object doesn't support this property or method

on line 8, char 1

What should I change? Thanks

Comment: @Malbordio My bad. You need the `Set` keyword for assigning an object. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can break up the GetObject line:

```
Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_PingStatus WHERE address = '" & strComputer & "'")
```

When I run the script (I replaced the Echo with MsgBox but it shouldn't matter) it works fine:

```
strComputers = "192.168.1.1,192.168.1.4,100.100.100.100"
arrComputers = Split(strComputers, ",")

For Each strComputer In arrComputers
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_PingStatus WHERE address = '" & strComputer & "'")
    For Each objPingStatus In objPing
        If IsNull(objPingStatus.StatusCode) Or objPingStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
            If strFailedPings <> "" Then strFailedPings = strFailedPings & vbCrLf
            strFailedPings = strFailedPings & strComputer
        End If
    Next
Next

If strFailedPings = "" Then
    MsgBox "Ping status of specified computers is OK"
Else
    MsgBox "Ping failed for the following computers:" & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strFailedPings
End If
```